# Two Column Array from Two Column MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, foreach

I am trying to write a script that will do two things:

1) Run through a two column table and then push the contents into a two column array

2) Run through that two column array (made in thing #1) and re-insert it back to a two column MySQL table.

Here's my attempt of thing #1:

```
//grab desired product options incase of 'undo'
$optionArray = array();
$fabricArray = array();
$optionSelect = "SELECT * FROM $clientOptions WHERE bag_id ='$bagID' ";
$optionResult = mysql_query($optionSelect, $db_bags);
while ($optionData = mysql_fetch_assoc($optionResult)){
        $optionSku = $optionData['option_sku']; 
        $fabricSku = $optionData['fabric_sku']; 
        array_push($optionArray, $optionSku);
        array_push($fabricArray, $fabricSku);
        array_push($optionArray, $fabricArray);
}
$_SESSION['options_array'] = $optionArray;
```

Here is my attempt at thing #2:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['options_array'] as $optionSku){
    foreach ($optionSku as $fabricSku){
        $insertOption = "INSERT INTO $clientOptions (bag_id, product_sku, option_sku, fabric_sku) VALUES ('$bagID', '$productSku', '$optionSku', '$fabricSku')";
        mysql_query($insertOption, $db_bags);
    }//end of fabric sku for loop
}//end of option sku for loop
```

- Notices: Yes, I have to do this way... no I can't just transfer it from one MySQL table to the next. Yes, I have to use sessions.

General Purpose: is to all the user to undo a remove feature. User can remove a product and its options, then given notice to "undo" that remove. The product just removed is stored in a session and the options (and fabrics) are stored in a session array.

Comment: why not just put a flag in the database to mark the field as inactive and then allow the user to reactivate their record?

Comment: Just trying to keep the database light. Don't want every product the users added and deletes to be stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you are building will look like this:

```
optionArray[0] = optionSku
optionArray[1] = array(fabricSku)
```

and so on...

If want the data altogether you would want something like this:

```
optionArray[0] = array(optionSku, fabricSku)
```

To do that you would want to do this:

```
while ($optionData = mysql_fetch_assoc($optionResult)){
        $optionSku = $optionData['option_sku']; 
        $fabricSku = $optionData['fabric_sku']; 
        array_push($optionArray, array($optionSku, $fabricSku));
}
```

And I would end up reducing that to:

```
while ($optionData = mysql_fetch_assoc($optionResult)){
        array_push($optionArray, array($optionData['option_sku'], $optionData['fabric_sku']));
}
```

Then your loop would be (though I am not sure where bagID or productSku are coming from):

```
foreach($_SESSION['options_array'] as $optionSkuData) {
    $insertOption = "INSERT INTO $clientOptions (bag_id, product_sku, option_sku, fabric_sku) VALUES ('$bagID', '$productSku', '$optionSkuData[0]', '$optionSkuData[1]')";
    mysql_query($insertOption, $db_bags);
}
```

Comment: Yep that did it... thanks. The productSku and BagID are being called from above in the script.. not vital to my question but thanks for being thorough